# How post both formData's files and user infos with Axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, form-data

I have a formData that contains images as Blobs. I can send these to my server with axios. I need to add the user id (a string) to my post request as well. So I shall access both req.file and req.body in my express server.

How to do it? Here is my code:

```js
export async function uploadImages(files, userId) {
  try {
    const images = new FormData();
    if ([files].length > 0) {
      return Object.values(files).forEach((file: File) =>
        images.append("image", file.blob, file.name)
      );
    }
    //TODO: ADD USERID TO THE POST REQUEST
    const res = await ax.post(
      process.env.SERVER_URL + "/upload-images",
      images
    );
    return console.log("success", res);
  } catch (err) {
    return console.log("error", err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try simply add fields to FormData with necessary info?

Comment: Yes, I've written images.append("user", userId) but the api request is never performed then. It's either only files, or only userId. I'm stuck here...

Comment: Did you check `req.body` and `req.files`?

Comment: Yes, I console.loggued req as a whole. It is never triggered. The api call is not performed if there are both userId and images in the same formData. I'm doing something wrong but what?

Comment: And what error did you get on front-end side if you didn't reach your back-end route?

Comment: Ok found the error... It's because I wrote "return" in the loop. So the function stopped and would not trigger the api call.